# Check whatever a vector is pointing toward the interior of a closed polygon

Tags: vectors

Let's $(P)$ be a closed polygon with vertices $P_k, k=0,\cdots n$(modulo $n$). How to check if  $\vec{J}=\vec{P_kP_{k-1}}+\vec{P_kP_{k+1}}$ points towards the exterior (resp. interior) of $(P)$.

Comment: How is defined your "non-convex" set $S$ ? Do you mean there is a function $f$ such that $f(x)<0 \iff x \in S$ and that you are in a point $x_0 \in \partial S$ (classical notation for the border of $S$) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie it's defined by an indexed family of "n+1" points with street lines between the "j" point and the "j-1" and "j+1" (when j = n then it will be 0 instead of j+1) points so there is no function defined explicitly

Comment: @JeanMarie also the vector "J" that I am interested in is the sum of the normalized vectors from the j point to the j-1 point and the one from j to j+1 points

Comment: I think that checking the signed angle between the vector from the j to the j+1 points and the "J" vector (defined in the previous comment) will do the job

Comment: You should integrate all these comments into your question, mentionning the term "closed polygon" right at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these elements of information that you hadn't given, here is an answer.

Therefore, you have a closed polygon $(P)$ with vertices $P_k, k=0,\cdots n$ (modulo $n$). If $(P)$ is traversed in the direct sense (trigonometric orientation), $(P)$ will be situated "on the left hand side" by a vehicule following the border.

This said, it is easy to see that $J=\vec{P_kP_{k-1}}+\vec{P_kP_{k+1}}$ will point towards the exterior (resp. interior) of $(P)$ if $P_k$ is a point of concavity (resp. convexity) of polygon $(P)$.

As you have remarked, testing whether a point is a point of concavity (resp. convexity) of the border $\partial (P)$ is done by computing the nature of orientation change, which is easy to compute without dealing with angles through the sign of the determinant

$$\det(\vec{P_{k-1}P_k},\vec{P_kP_{k+1}}) ;$$

if it is $<0$ (resp. $>0$), it is a point of concavity (resp. convexity).

Comment: This is an interesting result do you know a good course (pdf) that has such a result and much more if possible. (In french would be great)

Comment: I am almost certain to find something but I need to know your level of study (and/or the big "areas" of maths you know) in order that I can give you readable references.

Comment: Third year of license in mathematics

Comment: A first reference with the keyword "analytic geometry" (géométrie analytique) in french from the university of Liège in Belgium (with a good pedagogical approach) :  https://www.facsa.uliege.be/upload/docs/application/pdf/2018-03/geometrie_-_synthese.pdf Say if you find it a little too elementary ; I will look for other references.